How to prove this inequality: $2\arctan\frac{b-a}{2}\ge\arctan b-\arctan a$ $(b≥a）$
$2\arctan\frac{b-a}{2}\ge\arctan b-\arctan a$ $(b≥a）$

Since "$\arctan b-\arctan a=arctan\frac{b-a}{1+ab}$" holds for $ab\neq-1\\$ and with the monotonicity of function $arctanx$
I can easily show $2\arctan\frac{b-a}{2}\ge\arctan\frac{b-a}{1+ab}$ when $ab\in (-∞,-1) \cup[1,+∞)\\$
and for $ab\in[-1,0]$ (It shows that $b≥0≥a$) I use convexity of the function $arctanx$ to prove:
$2\arctan\frac{b+(-a)}{2}\ge\arctan b+\arctan (-a)$
But, when it comes to $ab\in(0,1)$,I wasn't able to work it out.

Here's a more analysis/caculus oriented answer. First let $c=-a$ then the inequality in question becomes $$\arctan \frac{b + c}2\ge \frac12(\arctan b + \arctan c),\quad b + c\ge 0$$
Let $m=\frac{b + c}2\ge 0, d = \frac{b - c}2$ then we further rewrite it as
$$\begin{align}\arctan m &\ge \frac12(\arctan (m + d) + \arctan (m - d))\end{align}$$
Treating RHS as a function in $d\in\Bbb R$ where $m\ge0$ is fixed, then its derivative
$$f'(d)=\frac{-4md}{(1+(d+m)^2)(1+(d-m)^2))}$$
It's easy to see $f'(d)\le 0$ when $d\ge 0$ and $f'(d)\ge 0$ when $d\le 0$. Therefore $f$ must attain its maximum value at $d=0$. Therefore given any $m\ge0$ we have
$$\arctan m= f(0) \ge f(d)= \frac12(\arctan (m + d) + \arctan (m - d)),\quad\forall d\in\Bbb R$$
which is exactly the desired inequality in the rewritten form.

$\textbf{Hint}$: Convert both expressions into a single arctan
$$2\arctan\frac{b-a}{2} = \arctan\frac{b-a}{1-\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2}+\pi\cdot H(b-a-2)$$
$$\arctan b - \arctan a = \arctan\frac{b-a}{1+ba}+\pi\cdot H(ba+1)$$
where $H(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside step function.

You can see here that you need to consider three cases in the $ab$ plane - $ba\leq -1$, $2\leq y-x \leq \sqrt{4+(x+y)^2}$, and $2\geq y-x \geq -\sqrt{4+(x+y)^2}$ (the last two being a more compact way to include the $ba\geq -1$ case). When you have two parameters that vary, you should not be thinking in terms of intervals at all, but instead of regions of 2D space which may or may not be rectangular (in this case, most definitely not).

The non-trivial case is $b > a$.
The desired inequality is written as
$$2\arctan\frac{b-a}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}
\ge \arctan b - \arctan a - \frac{\pi}{2}. \tag{1}$$
Since both sides of (1) are in $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, it suffices to prove that
$$\tan \left(2\arctan\frac{b-a}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\ge \tan\left(\arctan b - \arctan a - \frac{\pi}{2}\right),$$
or
$$\tan \left(\arctan\frac{b-a}{2} - \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan \frac{b-a}{2}\right)\right)
\ge -\frac{1}{\tan (\arctan b - \arctan a)},$$
or
$$\frac{(b-a)^2 - 4}{4(b-a)} \ge - \frac{1+ab}{b-a},$$
or
$$\frac{(a+b)^2}{4(b-a)} \ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.
